# How to make two x-axes in left and right with scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a cluster using scatter plot with two x-axes, in left and right side, not in top and bottom. I have checked out similar questions  but it doesn't seem to be the problem here.
I was trying to make this two plots share y axis with 2 x-axes in left and right side, but I cannot make it.

This is my plot,
[image]

but I expect my plot to be displayed like this
[image].

This is the code I have tried.

```
import pylab as py
filename1="ex_1.csv"
df1=pd.read_csv(filename1)
filename2="ex_21.csv"
df2=pd.read_csv(filename2)
x1 = df1['Dom']
y1 = df1['Sal']
s1 = df1['Size']
x2 = df2['Type']
y2 = df2['Sal']
s2 = df2['Size']
d  = 2.0

#plot 1
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
fig, (gb1, gb2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize=(10,6),sharey = True)
gb1.scatter(x=x1, y=y1, s=s1*50, alpha=0.8, c="blue", label=x1)
gb2.scatter(x=x2, y=y2, s=s2*50, alpha=0.8, c="red")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please clarify what exactly you want to change. Is it that you want to turn off the spines around the outside? Do you want to reduce the padding between the two subplots? Also, it's easier for people to experiment with your code if you include a runnable example that doesn't require data files. Using random numbers with a fixed seed is often useful.

Comment: Matplotlib has a nice summary of how to [create and arrange subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=shared%20axis) and [how to create parasite axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your categories are different, you can just use a single plot and draw a line in between.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111)
x1 = np.array(['A','B','C','A','B','C'])
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

x2 = np.array(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'])
y2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])


ax.scatter(x1, y1, s=y1*50, c='b')
ax.scatter(x2, y2, s=y2*50, c='r')
ax.axline((2.5, 1), (2.5, 6), c='black')
ax.figure.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comment, changed `import pylab` to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` as `pylab` can cause unexpected behavior and is strongly discouraged by [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab)